# Is it fine to pray for Firdaws for me and the Muslims?

Tags: sunni

For example, is it fine if I pray
"Ya Allah, please grant me and the Muslims Firdaws amin"?

Or am I supposed to just pray for myself and not for all Muslims?

Similarly, can I include all Muslims in every supplication? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Ofcourse you can, You can pray for yourself.which is the most important thing, your parents, friends and all Muslims too.

Scholars has emphasized on making Dua'a for the "Parents". They say if you don't mention your parents when you make Dua'a then it means you are not treating them just as you must treat them according to Islam( aka Aqouq al-Waldeen).

---

Here are 2 hadiths regarding the reward of praying to Muslims

> Abud-Darda' reported:
>   The Messenger of Allah (PBUH) said,
>
> "The supplication of a Muslim for his (Muslim) brother in his absence will certainly be answered. Everytime he makes a supplication for good for his brother, the angel appointed for this particular task says: 'A meen! May it be for you, too'."

[Muslim](http://www.sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/17#31)

> Abud-Darda' (May Allah be pleased with him) reported:
>   I heard the Messenger of Allah () saying, "Whenever a Muslim supplicates for his (Muslim) brother in his absence, the angels say: 'May the same be for you too'."

Muslim